# Inserting unicode into MySQL database from python script

Tags: python, mysql, tweepy

I am trying to retrieve the text, longitude, and latitude from a tweepy StreamListener and then store the data in my SQL database. I am able to store the coordinates fine, but for some reason the unicode is not working. 
For the SQL I have:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE tweets (tweet nvarchar(140), lat float(10,6) not null, lng float(10,6) not null) engine=myisam;
```

For my python script I have (not including the main()):

```
import mysql.connector
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from authenticator import Authenticator
import json


#connecting to mysql database
conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='arlenyu123',host='localhost',database='twitter')
mycursor = conn.cursor()


class MyStreamListener(StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):
        if status.coordinates is not None:
            #for some reason the status text isn't being fed into the database properly... not sure why.
            mycursor.execute('INSERT INTO tweets (tweet, lat, lng) VALUES ({},{},{})'.
                format(status.text, status.coordinates['coordinates'][0], status.coordinates['coordinates'][1]))
    return True

def on_error(self, status_code):
    if status_code == 403:
        print("The request is understood, but it has been refused or access is not allowed. Limit is maybe reached")
        return False
```

Please note that I am a beginner so any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Try to run `SET NAMES UTF8;` in the MySQL shell.

Comment: ALTER TABLE tweets CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4

Comment: As @MONTYHS said, just alter the table to accept unicode. Its your data and your database, so just change the database to accept unicode is by far the simplest and most correct solution in my opinion for your situation. This topic known as "string encoding" can be overwhelming for developers. Dont get hung up on these at a beginner level. Note, you can use MySQL Workbench as a graphical frontend to handle the administration and table alteration. It can be very convenient.

Answer (score 0):

You should *never* use string interpolation to create SQL commands. Use the parameter substitution that is provided by the SQL connector.

```
 mycursor.execute('INSERT INTO tweets (tweet, lat, lng) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)',
                  (status.text, status.coordinates['coordinates'][0], status.coordinates['coordinates'][1]))
```